# How to convert a char array to a byte array?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, char

I'm working on my project and now I'm stuck with a problem that is, how can I convert a char array to a byte array?.

For example: I need to convert `char[9]` `"fff2bdf1"` to a byte array that is `byte[4]` is `0xff,0xf2,0xbd,0xf1`.

Comment: So you want to parse the hex values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little Arduino sketch illustrating one way to do this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  char arr[] = "abcdef98";
  byte out[4];
  auto getNum = [](char c){ return c > '9' ? c - 'a' + 10 : c - '0'; };
  byte *ptr = out;

  for(char *idx = arr ; *idx ; ++idx, ++ptr ){
    *ptr = (getNum( *idx++ ) << 4) + getNum( *idx );
  }


  //Check converted byte values.
  for( byte b : out )
    Serial.println( b, HEX );  
}

void loop() {
}
```

The loop will keep converting until it hits a null character. Also the code used in `getNum`only deals with lower case values. If you need to parse uppercase values its an easy change. If you need to parse both then its only a little more code, I'll leave that for you if needed (let me know if you cannot work it out and need it).

This will output to the serial monitor the 4 byte values contained in `out` after conversion.

> AB
>   CD
>   EF
>   98

**Edit: How to use different length inputs.**

The loop does not care how much data there is, as long as there are an even number of inputs (two ascii chars for each byte of output) plus a single terminating null. It simply stops converting when it hits the input strings terminating null.

So to do a longer conversion in the sketch above, you only need to change the length of the output (to accommodate the longer number). I.e:

```
char arr[] = "abcdef9876543210";
byte out[8];
```

The `4` inside the loop doesn't change. It is shifting the first number into position.

For the first two inputs (`"ab"`) the code first converts the 'a' to the number `10`, or hexidecimal `A`. It then shifts it left 4 bits, so it resides in the upper four bits of the byte: `0A` to `A0`. Then the second value `B` is simply added to the number giving `AB`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I'm trying to understand your code and edit it to the case of an array of 6 bytes. I edited the number '4' to 6 but it's not work.
Can you explain a little bit further about your code?.

Comment: @TrungPhạmKhánh I have edited the end of the question with an explanation.

Comment: How to parse only upper case? If the `char arr[] = "ABCDEF98"`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to parse the hex values in your string, and two letters always make up one byte value (so you use leading zeros), you can use `sscanf` like this:

```
char input[] = "fff2bdf1"; 
unsigned char output[4];
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  sscanf(&input[i*2], "%02xd", &output[i]);
}
```

Comment: what is data, &data[i]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since this solution acutally provides the format like `0x31` like asked.

Answer (score -1):

Just shift 0 or 1 to its position in binary format :)

```
char lineChars[8] = {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1}; 
    char lineChar = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<8;i++)
    {
        lineChar |= lineChars[i] << (7-i);
    }
```

Example 2. But is not tested!

```
void abs()
{
  char* charData = new char;
  *charData = 'h';
  BYTE* byteData = new BYTE;
  *byteData = *(BYTE*)charData; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what's going on in your code? I don't understand how this parses hex values.