# Convert Hex char array to Byte array Arduino

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

How to convert the char array to Byte array?

```
char CardNumber[8] = "B763AB23"; // Length is 8, basically it's in Hex
                                 // B7 63 AB 23
```

I need to convert it into Byte array to `byte CardNumberByte[4];` So basically, it should be like :

```
CardNumberByte[0] = B7;
CardNumberByte[1] = 63;
CardNumberByte[2] = AB;
CardNumberByte[3] = 23;
```

I am unable to find any solution for that.

Comment: The solution is here this will solve your problem. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581925/how-to-convert-a-char-array-to-a-byte-array-on-arduino)

Answer (score 0):

Eight hex characters is 32 bits, so first put the number in a long (32-bit on the Arduino) value:

```
long number = (long) strtol(&CardNumber[0], NULL, 16);
```

Then bit-shift the values into bytes:

```
CardNumberByte[0] = number >> 24;
CardNumberByte[1] = number >> 16 & 0xFF;
CardNumberByte[2] = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
CardNumberByte[3] = number & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
union 
{
uint32_t number;
uint8_t CardNumberByte[4];
} CardNum;

char cn[] = "B763AB23";
```

and "conversion":

```
CardNum.Number = strtol(cn, NULL, 16);
```

and your bytes are avaiable via

```
CardNum.CardNumberByte[xx]
```

But I think you should start from the begginers C++ tutorial and learn some basics.