# Python's binascii.unhexlify function in C

Tags: c, string, arduino, hex, ascii

I'm building a program that takes input as if it is a bare MAC address and turn it into a binary string. I'm doing this on a embedded system so there is no STD. I have been trying something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620891/handling-of-conversions-from-and-to-hex) but after 2 days I haven't achieved anything, I'm really bad with these kind of things.

What I wanted is output to be equal to goal, take this into consideration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char* goal = "\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff";
    printf("Goal: %s\n", goal);

    char* input = "aabbccddeeff";
    printf("Input: %s\n", input);

    char* output = NULL;
    // Magic code here

    if (output == goal) {
        printf("Did work! Yay!");
    } else {
        printf("Did not work, keep trying");
    }
}
```

Thanks, this is for a personal project and I really want to finish it

Comment: You need to allocate space to store your output; `char *output = NULL:` doesn't do that.  You need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings; using `==` doesn't work (it compares two pointer values; unless you do `output = goal;` (or `goal = output;`), the comparison will fail).  You've not even shown a basic attempt to convert `aa` into `\xaa`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a char array to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581925/how-to-convert-a-char-array-to-a-byte-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your comparison should use `strcmp` else it'll be always wrong.

Then, I would read the string 2-char by 2-char and convert each "digit" to its value (0-15), then compose the result with shifting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// helper function to convert a char 0-9 or a-f to its decimal value (0-16)
// if something else is passed returns 0...
int a2v(char c)
{
    if ((c>='0')&&(c<='9'))
    {
        return c-'0';
    }
    if ((c>='a')&&(c<='f'))
    {
        return c-'a'+10;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    const char* goal = "\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff";
    printf("Goal: %s\n", goal);

    const char* input = "aabbccddeeff";
    int i;

    char output[strlen(input)/2 + 1];
    char *ptr = output;

    for (i=0;i<strlen(input);i+=2)
    {

       *ptr++ = (a2v(input[i])<<4) + a2v(input[i]);
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
    printf("Goal: %s\n", output);

    if (strcmp(output,goal)==0) {
        printf("Did work! Yay!");
    } else {
        printf("Did not work, keep trying");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tested it and it works flawlessly, finally!